# Why is my JavaScript loop jumping 10 index places at a time?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a for loop that is returning an unexpected result. Here is the code:

```
var matArray = scrolls;
        var offset = $scope.offset;
        for(var i = 0; i < matArray.length; i++) {
            var pointer = (i + offset) % matArray.length;
            console.log(matArray[pointer]);
        }
```

What I am expecting to get is the loop to begin at a specific index, and then continue in a normal loop until all the way around the results. But instead, THE LOOP JUMPS 10 INDEX SPOTS EACH TIME. If I hardcode in the offset, for example:

```
var matArray = scrolls;
        var offset = $scope.offset;
        for(var i = 0; i < matArray.length; i++) {
            var pointer = (i + 1) % matArray.length;
            console.log(matArray[pointer]);
        }
```

It works as expected, beginning at the second index.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don’t you log `$scope.offset` and see what value it has?

Comment: May be an `offset` is a **string**

Comment: Also add AngularJS to the tags if you're using it.

Comment: Why don't you just init `var i = $scope.offset` in your loop?

Comment: @isvforall, you have hit the nail on the head. That must be it. Explains the factor 10 very well.

Comment: I don't see the point of using stackoverflow as debug environment :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems your problem in that you add the **string** to a **number**, in JavaScript it will be concatenated into a **string**, e.g.:

```
'9' + 1 // will be '91'
```

You could use `parseInt` function:

```
var offset = parseInt($scope.offset, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.offset` is probably the string '1' when you expect it to be a number.
Note that `+(0 + '1')` is `0`, and `+(1 + '1')` is `11`.

Change `i + offset` to `i + +offset` to convert `offset` to a number before adding it to `i`:

```
var matArray = scrolls;
var offset = $scope.offset;
for(var i = 0; i < matArray.length; i++) {
    var pointer = (i + +offset) % matArray.length;
    console.log(matArray[pointer]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var pointer = (i +  parseInt(offset, 10)) % matArray.length;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are not beneficial for other users, having a similar problem.